# Query with JOIN FETCH performance problem

Tags: java, hibernate

I have problem with hibernate query performance which I can't figure out. In code snippet below I need select entities with at least one mapping and filtered mapping. I'm using FETCH JOIN for this to load only filtered mappings.
But in that case I have performance problems with query. Hibernate says warning log :

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl
>   - firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in
>   memory!

When I omit FETCH JOIN and left only JOIN query is nice fast. But in result I have all mappings loaded to entity which is not acceptable state for me. Is there a way to boost query performance? There are a lot rows in mapping table.

HQL query :

```
select distinct e from Entity 
   join fetch e.mappings as mapping 
where e.deleted = 0 and e.mappings is not empty 
   and e = mapping.e and mapping.approval in (:approvals)
```

Entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entity")
class Entity {

   ...

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="entity", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @OrderBy("created")
   private List<Mapping> mappings = new ArrayList<Mapping>();

   ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="mapping")
class Mapping {

public static enum MappingApproval {
    WAITING, // mapping is waiting for approval
    APPROVED, // mapping was approved
    DECLINED; // mapping was declined
}

...

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="entity_id", nullable=false)
    private Entity entity;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="approval", length=20)
    private MappingApproval approval;

...

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show SQL queries issued by Hibernate?

Comment: @axtavt I've added SQL queries from Hibenate. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is it a query for `JOIN` or `FETCH JOIN`? Where is another one?

Comment: @axtavt This one is for FETCH JOIN, for only JOIN variant there are exactly same query but no following queries for mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after increasing memory for JVM things goes much better. After all I end with not using FETCH in queries.

Comment: In any strange situation, just increase heap size :)

Answer (score 4):

From the JPA-Specifications

> The effect of applying setMaxResults or setFirstResult to a query
>   involving  fetch joins over collections is undefined. (JPA "Enterprise
>   JavaBeans 3.0,  Final Release", Kapitel 3.6.1 Query Interface)

Hibernate does the right thing, but executes a part of the query in memory, which is tremendously slower. In my case the difference is between 3-5 ms to 400-500 ms.

My solution was to implement the paging within the query itself. Works fast with the JOIN FETCH.

Comment: you should really specify how to do this. That's the difference between an answer and a great answer. https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/

Answer (score 2):

If you need a firstResult/maxResults with "fetch" you can split your query in 2 queries:

1. Query your entity ids with firstResult/maxResults but without the "fetch" on sub-tables:

   ```
   select entity.id from entity (without fetch) where .... (with firstResult/maxResults)
   ```
2. Query your entities with the "fetch" on the ids returned by your first query:

   ```
   select entity from entity fetch ... where id in <previous ids>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is slow is because Hibernate executes the SQL query with no pagination at all and the restriction is done in memory.

However, if the join has to scan and fetch 100k records, while you are interested in just 100 results, then 99.9% of the work being done by the Extractor and all the I/O done over networking is just waste.

You can easily turn a JPQL query that uses both [`JOIN FETCH`](https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/) and pagination:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    where p.title like :title
    order by p.id
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("title", titlePattern)
.setMaxResults(maxResults)
.getResultList();
```

into an SQL query that limits the result using `DENSE_RANK` by the parent identifier:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "PostWithCommentByRank",
    query =
        "SELECT * " +
        "FROM (   " +
        "    SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY \"p.created_on\", \"p.id\") rank " +
        "    FROM (   " +
        "        SELECT p.id AS \"p.id\", " +
        "               p.created_on AS \"p.created_on\", " +
        "               p.title AS \"p.title\", " +
        "               pc.id as \"pc.id\", " +
        "               pc.created_on AS \"pc.created_on\", " +
        "               pc.review AS \"pc.review\", " +
        "               pc.post_id AS \"pc.post_id\" " +
        "        FROM post p  " +
        "        LEFT JOIN post_comment pc ON p.id = pc.post_id " +
        "        WHERE p.title LIKE :titlePattern " +
        "        ORDER BY p.created_on " +
        "    ) p_pc " +
        ") p_pc_r " +
        "WHERE p_pc_r.rank <= :rank ",
    resultSetMapping = "PostWithCommentByRankMapping"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "PostWithCommentByRankMapping",
    entities = {
        @EntityResult(
            entityClass = Post.class,
            fields = {
                @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "p.id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "createdOn", column = "p.created_on"),
                @FieldResult(name = "title", column = "p.title"),
            }
        ),
        @EntityResult(
            entityClass = PostComment.class,
            fields = {
                @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "pc.id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "createdOn", column = "pc.created_on"),
                @FieldResult(name = "review", column = "pc.review"),
                @FieldResult(name = "post", column = "pc.post_id"),
            }
        )
    }
)
```

The query can be executed like this:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager
.createNamedQuery("PostWithCommentByRank")
.setParameter(
    "titlePattern",
    "High-Performance Java Persistence %"
)
.setParameter(
    "rank",
    5
)
.unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
.setResultTransformer(
    new DistinctPostResultTransformer(entityManager)
)
.getResultList();
```

To transform the tabular result set back into an entity graph, you need a `ResultTransformer` which looks as follows:

```
public class DistinctPostResultTransformer
        extends BasicTransformerAdapter {
 
    private final EntityManager entityManager;
 
    public DistinctPostResultTransformer(
            EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
 
    @Override
    public List transformList(
            List list) {
             
        Map<Serializable, Identifiable> identifiableMap =
            new LinkedHashMap<>(list.size());
             
        for (Object entityArray : list) {
            if (Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(entityArray.getClass())) {
                Post post = null;
                PostComment comment = null;
 
                Object[] tuples = (Object[]) entityArray;
 
                for (Object tuple : tuples) {
                    if(tuple instanceof Identifiable) {
                        entityManager.detach(tuple);
 
                        if (tuple instanceof Post) {
                            post = (Post) tuple;
                        }
                        else if (tuple instanceof PostComment) {
                            comment = (PostComment) tuple;
                        }
                        else {
                            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                                "Tuple " + tuple.getClass() + " is not supported!"
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
 
                if (post != null) {
                    if (!identifiableMap.containsKey(post.getId())) {
                        identifiableMap.put(post.getId(), post);
                        post.setComments(new ArrayList<>());
                    }
                    if (comment != null) {
                        post.addComment(comment);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(identifiableMap.values());
    }
}
```

That's it!