# Hibernate : QueryImpl list method Performance

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, query-performance

For our report UI we query the sessions object and list it in the screen. To query the data we use `Hibernate` and a [Generic Dao](https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/) implementation. Before use [Dynatrace](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/index.html) we always blame database about this query but after start to use DynaTrace it shows us that the bottleneck is in the code at [QueryImpl.list](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.19.Final/org/hibernate/Query.java#Query.list%28%29) method. We have really bad performance both Prod and Dev, The total count records are about 2M in PROD and it takes 75 seconds(yes more than 1 minute :( ) Below screenshots show the Dynatrace Screenshots which show us problem is in Hibernate QueryImpl list method. I checked the application in DEV environment with 500K records and it takes 30 seconds in DEV too and same methods takes the 28 seconds at this query. I track the application get heap dump and analyze in dynatrace and [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html). Also check thread dumps both at [samurai](http://samuraism.jp/samurai/en/index.html) and dyntarace but can not find any locked Thread or a lot of special class instance. I share dynatrace pure paths screenshots and our method call which use Spring `@Transactional` annotation.

ReadOnly.java

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public @interface ReadOnly {

}
```

SessionService.java

```
@Override
@ReadOnly
public SearchResult<Session> getReport(ISearch search) {
       return sessionDao.searchAndCount(search);
}
```

SessionDao.java

```
public <RT> SearchResult<RT> searchAndCount(ISearch search) {
       if (search == null) {
            SearchResult<RT> result = new SearchResult<RT>();
            result.setResult((List<RT>) getAll());
            result.setTotalCount(result.getResult().size());
            return result;
        }
      return searchAndCount(persistentClass, search);
}
```

I spend 2-3 days to investigate this problem and i really want to learn the reason.

[image]

**EDIT:** I query 50 records form a 2M table, i use pagination approach and in screenshots i mentioned that it takes 2.5 seconds in database but it spends 75 seconds in memory QueryImpl list method. So I already query 50 records from 2M table which has index in date fields. Please check screenshot red rectangulars.

Comment: Ofcourse it is slow... You issue a query, return 2 million rows all those rows are translated into objects! Creating an object is pretty fast, but 2 million times well that adds up!. Don't write a query that returns ALL the rows in the database, that is plain wrong imho.

Comment: Following M. Deinum comment, I think the real question is why do you need to load these 2M objects ?
Depending on your need, you should probably do some DB side aggregation or use a window (start index + nb rows) to fetch only the viewable rows

Comment: @M.Deinum please check the edit.

Comment: No you don't... You are doing a `getAll` your code shows  no sign of paging what so ever. Also depending on your database, paging might be slow as it might retrieve more then you think. Also you have hibernate, which uses mappings, if you have eager collections or other joins you might get an even larger cartesian product.

Comment: Basically without knowing your database, your entities and how your actual method works there is no useful information in your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum please mention other useful information for you. I didn't want to add a lot of logs which runnign sql statement because of SO best practice for questions. So I can provide used database and runnign sql statement.

Comment: I already gave the requested information... -> **without knowing your database, your entities and how your actual method works**..

Comment: How long does the query take? Copy paste the query and execute it in something like TOAD or whatever you use. If that already takes 25seconds you might have a mapping issue, amount of data etc.

Comment: I mentioned in edit it takes 2.5 seconds in PROD 2M data. Now i get the exact running query and run it in DEV 500K data in sql console. Btw i believe just you mention we have a problem in pagination but this 2.5 seconds i don't understand let me check. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your help i post an answer about my problem. If you write an answer i can accept and up vote it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all thanks @M.Deinum for his comments which help us to address the problem. Problem is described at below SO questions :

- [Question and Accepted Answer describe the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258556/org-hibernate-hql-ast-querytranslatorimpl-list-attention-firstresult-maxresults)
- [Another related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944985/query-with-join-fetch-performance-problem)
- [Accepted answer made useful suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431670/how-can-i-avoid-the-warning-firstresult-maxresults-specified-with-collection-fe)

In my case first running and takes 75 seconds at PROD query is below.

SessionWithJOINFETCH.sql

```
SELECT
    session0.*,
    cardholder0.*,
    transaction0.*
FROM
    MSU_SESSION session0 LEFT OUTER JOIN MSU_CARD_HOLDER cardholder0
        ON session0.card_holder_id = cardholder0_.id LEFT OUTER JOIN MSU_TRANSACTION transaction0
        ON session0.id = transaction0_.session_id
WHERE
    (
        session0.status IN(
            ? ,
            ?
        )
    )
    AND(
        session0.sessionType IS NULL
        OR session0.sessionType IN(
            ? ,
            ?
        )
    )
    AND session0.session_create_timestamp >= ?
    AND session0.session_create_timestamp <= ?
ORDER BY
    session0.session_create_timestamp DESC
```

and also in log i see that WARNING:

> firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in
>   memory!

It means we use pagination(for Oracle rowNum) in memory. It can be seen at first runnig sql it hasn't any rowNum, it gets all the data according to criteria and then "firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!" applying firstResult/maxResult in memory and it takes time.

The reason is we are using `JOIN FETCH` with `setMaxResult`. According to Hibernate forums and above SO question links it is a hibernate feature so you shouldn't be use `setMaxResult` with `JOIN FETCH`(at least with 1-N relation) after remove this relation below sql is created by hibernate and its performance is better better now.

AfterRemoveJOINFETCH.sql

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
             session0_.*
        FROM
            MSU_SESSION session0_
        WHERE
            (
                session0_.status IN(
                    ? ,
                    ?
                )
            )
            AND(
                session0_.sessionType IS NULL
                OR session0_.sessionType IN(
                    ? ,
                    ?
                )
            )
            AND session0_.session_create_timestamp >= ?
            AND session0_.session_create_timestamp <= ?
        ORDER BY
            session0_.session_create_timestamp DESC
    )
WHERE
    rownum <= ?
```

I don't know why it is created an inner sql but its performance is better than before now you can see `rownum` is added to query and pagination is done at DB level.

> firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in
>   memory!

warning is disappered too.